# Obtener cálculo de números random para comparar con EditText

Tags: android, edittext

Últimamente he estado intentando de muchas maneras como obtener el cálculo de los dos números random que se muestran en MainActivity para después compararlo con el campo de texto y indicar si el número introducido es correcto o no.

Aquí el código:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.miguel.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNum = random.nextInt(101);
    int randomNum2 = random.nextInt(101);
    String messageRandomNum = String.valueOf(randomNum);
    String messageRandomNum2 = String.valueOf(randomNum2);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textViewRandomNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.random_num);
    textViewRandomNum.setText(messageRandomNum);
    messageRandomNum2 = String.valueOf(randomNum2+ "= ");
    TextView textViewRandomNum2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.random_num2);
    textViewRandomNum2.setText(messageRandomNum2);

}

public int getCalculation(){
    //Aquí es donde intento obtener el cálculo de los mismos números que se muestran en la pantalla
    int calculation = randomNum + randomNum2;
    return calculation;
}

public void sendMessage (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
package com.example.miguel.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    int messageInt = Integer.parseInt(message);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);

    //La comparación de editText y el cálculo
    if(messageInt == mainActivity.getCalculation()){
        textView.setText("¡Bien!");
    }else{
        textView.setText("¡Mal!");
    }

    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_display_message);
    layout.addView(textView);
}
}
```

Siempre sale que el número introducido (aunque esté bien) muestra "¡Mal!". 
Creo que el cálculo hace una suma de números random, pero no de los que se muestran en pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

Forma más fácil es..

```
int numero_1 = (int)(Math.random()*100);
int numero_2 = (int)(Math.random()*100);
int resultado = numero_1 + numero_2;
```

luego sólo asignas a cada `TextView` un valor
y en el `EditText` que escribas el resultado sólo tendrías que compararlo con tu variable `resultado`

Comment: No consigo corregirlo, el EditText lo capta bien. Es el calculo que usa números distintos al sumar

Comment: Puedes usar Logs para que visualices mejor tu programación

Comment: No te preocupes, ya lo solucioné ayer

Comment: Ps genial ha de haber sido algún error que no te hayas percatado

Comment: Aunque no me hayas ayudado, lo agradezco un montón ;) Muchas gracias!